# How to format multiple 'or' conditions in an if statement in Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python and am trying to implement multiple 'or' conditions to a single variable. I would like to know and understand the best way to format the following:

```
if ((word < 1) | (word > 10)):
   print "\n\n\nThe word entered is not valid!"
   print "Words that are valid are 1,2,7,8,9 and 10"
```

I want to compare '1' to numbers 5-10. Would it be something along the lines of:

```
 if ((word < 1) | (word > 10) and (word < 1) | (word >9) and (word < 1) and etc...):
   print "The word entered is not valid!"
   print "Words that are valid are between 1,2,7,8,9 and 10"
```

Numbers 1,2,7,8,9 and 10 are valid. Numbers 3,4,5,and 6 must be checked as less than to the variable of 'word'.

How would i do this?

Comment: First of all `|` is **bitwise or** while `or` is **boolean or**.

Comment: Is this what you want `1 <= word <= 10` to be a valid entered number?

Comment: More of comparing the variable 'word' to multiple integers with '1' being the only valid one and anything less than 1 or anything from 5 to 10 being invalid.

Comment: and what about 2,3,4,5, >10?

Comment: 2,3,4 would be valid as well.

Comment: You most likely want to do something like `word not in (1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 10)`, though it really isn't clear at all from your question

Comment: I apologize, my question should have been much more clear from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, `|` is bitwise-or.  You want:

```
if word < 1 or word > 10:
```

Per the question update, the following is one way to check for a specific set of values:

```
if word not in (1,2,7,8,9,10):
    print('invalid')
```

The equivalent and/or logic would be:

```
if word < 1 or (word > 2 and word < 7) or word > 10:
    print('invalid')
```

But you can see the `not in` way is simpler.

Comment: In Python, you would prefer to do : `if not (1 <= word <= 10):`

Comment: @VincentSavard, I don't not think that is false :)  It's really a matter of opinion.  I think the positive logic is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
if word < 1 or word == 10 or word > 15 or word == 11:
    print 'All will be considered'
```

Like mentioned, you can also do.

```
if word in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7):
    <do something>
```

or in range.

```
if word in range(0,10):
    <do something>
```

or will be true if any of them are true.  and will be true if ALL of them are true.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @mark-tolonen's answer, there's several ways to check if a *range* of numbers is less than something. One way would be explicitly using a loop:

```
less_than_word = True
for i in range(5, 10):
    if i > word:
        less_than_word = False 
        break

print('All values < word: {}'.format(less_than_word))
```

Alternatively, you can solve it with a combination of `all()` and `map()` (which however is harder to read if you are new to python, you can find the docs for `all()` and `map()` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)):

```
less_than_word = all(map(lambda x: x < word, range(5, 10)))
print('All values < word: {}'.format(less_than_word))
```

Yet another alternative would be to check whether the *largest* element of your sequence of numbers (5-10 in your example) is less than `word`. If so, they are all less than `word`, if not, then not.